# Does strokeRect: of NSBezierPath always draw a transparent rect? (Cocoa OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am trying to make a custom selection box for an image view I created and I am trying to use strokeRect: from NSBezierPath but it always seems to be transparent.  Called the method set to set the color the blackColor and then also tried using  olorWithDeviceRed:green:blue:alpha: but no matter what I have tried the rectangle created always seems to be transparent.  Is there a better method to use to draw an empty rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing the boundaries of your `strokeRect:`?

All `+strokeRect:` does is draw the outside edge defined by the rect. If you want to fill that rect as well you would need to call `[NSBezierPath fillRect:rect]`. In this case it will use the current fill color. Calling `-set` on a color sets the stroke and fill color but if you want to set it individually you'd call `-setFill` on your color object.